# I am trying to send the yield value from Python but I cannot see in the dictonrary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, generator

```py
guests = {}
def read_guestlist(file_name):
   text_file = open(file_name,'r')
   while True:
       line_data = text_file.readline().strip().split(",")
       yield line_data
       if len(line_data) < 2:
       # If no more lines, close file
          text_file.close()
          break
       name = line_data[0]
       age = int(line_data[1])
       guests[name] = age

guestlist = read_guestlist('guest_list.txt')
for i in range(10):
    next(guestlist)
guestlist.send('Jane,35')
```

This is the practice from Codacademy.
the given code read the text file, line by line, and split into half, name and ages, by ','.
Then put them in to the empty dictionary.
With the concept of generator, I suppose to send the yield value.

However, they provide me a string 'Jane,35' and send the value as I did before.

My question is the string cannot be read by 'readline()' and As I just naively did 'guestlist.send('Jane,35')', As I print geust dictionary, I cannot see the 'Jane, 35'
Should I change the position of 'yield line_data'? or What ought I have to do?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what is it you think that `guestlist.send()` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `with` statement to read the contents of the file line by line, then split each line and yield the split text thus meeting both almost all of the requirements inside the `read_gueslist` function

for example:

```
def read_guestlist(file_name):
   with open(filename) as text_file:
       for line in text_file:
           yield line.strip().split(',')
```

Then you can use the generator feature of the function to populate the guest dictionary.

```
for pair in read_guestlist(filename):
    guests.update([pair])
```

So altogether it might look something like this:

```
guests = {}

def read_guestlist(file_name):
   with open(filename) as text_file:
       for line in text_file:
           yield line.strip().split(',')

for pair in read_guestlist(filename):
    guests.update([pair])
```

This assumes that every line in your file has exactly two values separated by a single comma.  If that is not the case then you may have to do some error checking.